# Requiring modules in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was going through [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8)

Which approach is better requiring the modules at the top of the file or requiring them inside the separate function in the main file where they are used?

```
//main file
var stripe = require('stripe');

//inside function of main file
function makePayment(){
   var stripe= require('stripe');
}
```

Comment: if you want to use object for whole page or program so declare globally and if you use locally for particuler function so declare inside function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called for the first time on a given module file, `require()` uses synchronous I/O to load the file.  It is designed primarily for use during server initialization because you usually do not want to do synchronous I/O during the regular operation of a server because it can wreck the scalability of your server (due to the single threadedness of node.js Javascript).

As such, the usual convention is to load all your dependencies with `require()` at module initialization time, not during the normal execution of runtime functions in the module.

So, I'd recommend using:

```
const stripe = require('stripe');
```

somewhere near the top of your module file and not inside your function.